# How to prevent content theft from Facebook Instant articles

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

Currently, it is able to stop content theft from Wordpress. But my website is using facebook instant articles. Therefor some peoples are copying content from facebook instant articles. Is there any way to stop that?

[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3nJv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add this set of code in your body section of css....

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

I think this will solve your problem

Comment: Never knew this existed. But will this also work on FB Instant Articles